# Is there any way that we can customize the styling of Data Matrix of a QR code with Zxing library

Tags: java, android, kotlin, qr-code, zxing

[Customize Qr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOSvN.png)

I just want to customize my generated QR code like this I have tried many things but no sucess.

Comment: Why not just treat it as an image?